# Docker establish tcp communication between host and container

Tags: sockets, docker, tcp

I have a docker image that implements a tcp node via twisted and I would like to establish a communication to and from the host

on the host I start netcat

```
nc -l -p 6789
```

if I run the docker with

```
docker run -it -p 6789:6789 image_name
```

I get

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:6789 failed: port is already allocated
```

If I try the opposite order, so docker run and after start netcat on the host I get

```
Error: Couldn't setup listening socket (err=-3)
```

is there a way to bind an allocated port from the host to the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same port on the host to run `nc -l -p 6789` and to map the containers port (`-p 6789:6789`). Try to change one of them.

Comment: I need to communicate from host to container and viceversa, so the port needs to be open to send and receive messages

Comment: OK but there is no possible way to use the same port for two different services as docker and netcat. You can change to `nc -l -p 6788`  or use `-p 6788:6789`.

Comment: Thanks for help that fixed